# Dynamic regression and prewhitening

Tags: arima, sas, dynamic-regression

I'm working on a time series forecasting problem where sales needs to be predicted using weather variables. The weather variables are auto correlated and hence pre-whitening is needed to find the true relationship between each of the input variables with the target variable. I didn't come across a complete end to end process that needs to be followed. Based on my understanding, below is the detailed process. **Kindly take a look at it and let me know if the approach is right or not.** I am doing this in SAS and am using `PROC ARIMA`

1. Fit an ARIMA model to the input variable. Use this model to filter both the input and target time series and compute the cross correlation plot between them. The code for the same is as follows:

   ```
   proc arima data=in;
   identify var=temp;
   estimate p=1 q=1;
   identify var=sales crosscorr=temp;
   run;
   ```
2. If the CCF plot shows significant correlations at positive lags, the variable has an effect and can be used in the final model. Formulate the transfer function based on the CCF plot
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for all the input variables
4. If you feel the input variables are correlated among themselves, select one input variable as x variable and another input variable as target variable and repeat step 1. If the CCF shows only lags at 0, the two variables are highly correlated and one of them can be dropped from the final model for predicting the sales
5. Fit a model for the target variable( find p and q values) and use them along with the transfer functions for all the input variables identified

   ```
   proc arima data=in;
   identify var=sales;
   estimate p=1 q=1
            input = ( $(1)   temp
                      /(1 3) humidity);
   identify var=sales crosscorr=temp;
   run;
   ```
6. Forecast and see the model's performance metrics and fine tune if needed

Answer (score 2):

In a regression model it is the error (rather than the regressors) that we require to be non-autocorrelated. Autocorrelated regressors are OK; e.g. an AR($p$) process can be consistently estimated by OLS even though all the $p$ regressors as well as the response are autocorrelated. I am not sure whether you can reach your goal of *[finding] the true relationship between each of the input variables with the target variable* if you first transform your input variables. The relationship you will then find will be between transformed rather than original variables, which may complicate the interpretation.

Also, if you are interested in forecasting then you may not care much about finding *the true relationship between each of the input variables with the target variable*; instead, high forecast accuracy seems to be the relevant goal.

Comment: Sorry for a very late response. The objective of the above analysis is find out what drivers/variables in weather have an impact on the sales. And forecasting is done to measure the accuracy of the model developed. IMO, if pre-whitening is not done, spurious correlations are found between the input and target variables. So isn't it required?

Comment: Well, as I said, by changing the original variables you would have to change the interpretation accordingly. You would find relationships between *transformed* variables, and that may be more difficult to interpret. It might be difficult to distinguish between what is "genuine" and what is "spurious". Also, transfer function modelling might very well be suitable for autocorrelated variables, if I am not mistaken. But I may be unaware of some standard practices common in your industry, so take my opinion with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. It is very much appreciated. I just started working in time series forecasting and everything I found so far is by going through few articles. I'll consider your suggestion and see how it works out.