# Prewhitening Regressors in Lagged Time Series Regression

Tags: regression, time-series, lags, dynamic-regression

I'm trying to identify significant lags in a time series regression such that

$Y = \beta_0X_t + \beta_1X_{t-1} + ... + \beta_iX_{t-i} + \alpha_0Z_t + \alpha_1Z_{t-1} + ... + \alpha_jZ_{t-j}$

I realized that $X$ and $Z$ are autocorrelated processes so it's appropriate to "prewhiten" the independent variables using a process similar to the one outlined here:

https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/?q=book/export/html/54

[Dynamic regression and prewhitening](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181149/dynamic-regression-and-prewhitening)

I'm not super familiar with this type of analysis so I'm wondering the following:

1. After we've "prewhitened" the independent variable, do we fit the regression on the transformed variables (transformed from the estimated AR(MA) model on the independent variable) or do we just use the cross correlations to identify significant lags (variable selection)  and then fit the regression on those lags in the original space
2. In the case where we have two predictors ($X$ and $Z$) how do we prewhiten both variables. Is it iterative and independent? Or do we prewhiten (for example) $X$ first and then prewhiten $Z$ on the transformed $Y$ (after the prewhitening of $X$)?